# how to place struct in union

Tags: c++, arrays, unions

I have an union X. It's size is 64bits. How can I write (if possible) its declaration if I want to access those 64 bits as:

```
 1. 4 int16_t: p,q,r,s;
 2. Array of 4 int16_t: a[4]
 3. 2 int32_t: n, m;
 4. Array of 2 int32_t: b[2]
 5. 1 int64_t z;
```

Comment: too bad the search function in SO is broken :(

Comment: no, it's not homework. It just one of these very-easy-question-to-answer-but-hard-to-find-on-google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something like

```
union thingie_type {
    struct { int16_t p,q,r,s; };
    int16_t a[4];
    struct { int32_t n,m; };
    int32_t b[2];
    int64_t z;
};
```

Comment: bear in mind that this 'thingie_type' will almost certainly not work as intended.  byte alignments will create a nightmare without a substantial amount of architecture dependent command line switches for example.

Comment: KevinDTimm, true, but it's not about declaration. Well, p, a, n, b and z members are more fairly portable ;-)

Comment: My point is that while your solution answers the question, it will almost certainly not work when the OP tries to use it (unless, of course, the machine he compiles on has an 8 bit word)

Comment: KevinDTimm, of course, it's worth mentioning. And the fact that there may be a useful `#pragma` too ;-)

Comment: @ KevinDTimm: could you clarify your point? Won't compiler pack {p,q,r,s} into 64 bits?

Comment: ~buratinas, it is not guaranteed. Unless  you do some `#pragma pack` or whatever is good for your compiler.